# MPI on ARM - baremetal platform?

Tags: arm, mpi, benchmarking, bare-metal

Is MPI library supported by baremetal ARM system ? Does it work with ARM compilers? If yes, could anyone provide links/references, as I could not find it out .

Thanks

EDIT: I forgot to ask my main question. Is there any standard benchmark that uses  MPI library and can be used on ARM CORTEX - M4 ? For instance LINPACK with MPI which benchmarks the Floating point unit.

Comment: if you are looking for a standard MPI benchmark, you can try [OSU benchmark](http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/benchmarks/) or [Intel MPI](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mpi-benchmarks/)

Answer (score 1):

that should be no problem.
the easiest way to try this out is to use [OpenHPC](http://openhpc.community/downloads/)

mpich, mvapich2 and Open MPI are provided.

an other option is to download the sources of your best MPI library and build the lib by yourself (fwiw, i am pretty sure this is your only option if you want to use modern Fortran with non GNU fortran compiler)

Answer (score 0):

check out open MPI 2.1.1:

https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v2.1/

and here is how to build it:

https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/hpc/resources/porting-and-tuning/building-openmpi-with-arm-compiler

EDIT: i doubt that is benefical to use mpi on rtos/baremetal solution.

you can use uClinux for cortex m4 platform:

https://github.com/EmcraftSystems/linux-emcraft

Or you can try to porting mpi library to zephyr rtos: (a lot of work)

https://www.zephyrproject.org/

Comment: The second link provided has ubuntu OS,I would prefer baremetal examples and preferably in C